# Align paragraphs right to image (without wrapping)

Tags: css

I have a left floating image. How can I align content (multiple paragraphs) to the right, such that the do not wrap at the bottom of the image like the following:

```
+-----+
|     | Lorem Ipsum
|     | Lorem Ipsum
+-----+ Lorem Ipsum
        Lorem Ipsum
```

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BnQRW/509/) which shows the wrong behaviour. As soon as the image is over, the paragraph wraps. What do I have to change, to get the described result as above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `overflow:hidden` is one way to achieve that.

```
.content { overflow:hidden; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BnQRW/510/

Comment: Thanks! I already hat that, but my mistake was missing the leading dot in the css definition :(

Answer (score 0):

First create a container with a specified width:

```
<div class="container">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
  width:100%;
}
```

Let's add to columns, one column will take up 20% of the screen (this column will have the left content) and other column will take up 80% which will have the right content.

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="col-1-5">
      <p>Random Left Content</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-4-5">
     <p>Random Right Content</p>
  </div>

 </div>
```

Let's set all col's to float left and col-1-5 to 20% and col-4-5 to 80%

```
[class*='col-']{
    float:left;
 }
.col-4-5{
  width:80%;
  background:blue;
}
.col-1-5{
  width:20%;
  background:green;
}
```